# Datagridview - Disable Row-Select

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to get rid of the "row-Select-button" on the DataGridView?

[image]

Comment: You can set the [RowHeadersVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the DataGridView to false to hide the row headers. It doesn't prevent selecting the rows and you still can select rows by click on rows or by keyboard.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what i was searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set RawHeadersVisible false. See the picture for reference.

[image]

Or from the code you can do like

```
dgOrderList.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```